# Angular passing parameters from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs

Im a newbie in angular, trying to learn the language.

Got the following code: http://plnkr.co/edit/fuVb0mzhmDCKr1xKp7Rn?p=preview

Have a tab:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when
        ('/jobs', {templateUrl: 'jobs-partial.html',   controller: JobsCtrl  }).
      when
        ('/invoices', {templateUrl: 'invoices-partial.html',   controller: InvoicesCtrl }).
      when
        ('/payments', {templateUrl: 'payments-partial.html',   controller: PaymentsCtrl }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/jobs'});

      // make this demo work in plunker
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);
```

I would like to be able to access the selected tab from one the panel. How can I send parameters to the tab controllers?

Comment: You should use some service/factory: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/communicate-with-controllers-in-angular.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Service or Factory, inject that in to your `TabsCtrl`, save the currentTab state in that service in `ng-click`. Inject the same service in your Page controllers like `JobsCtrl`

```
app.factory('MyService',function(){

  var currentTab ;

  return {

      setCurrentTab : function(tab){
        currentTab = tab;
      },

      getCurrentTab : function(tab){
        return currentTab;
      }

  };

});
```

Update your `TabsCtrl` like below

```
function TabsCtrl($scope, $location, MyService) {
  // removing other code for brevity
  $scope.selectedTab = $scope.tabs[0];
  // saving the default tab state
  MyService.setCurrentTab($scope.tabs[0]);

  $scope.setSelectedTab = function(tab) {
    $scope.selectedTab = tab;
    // saving currentTab state on every click
    MyService.setCurrentTab(tab);
  }

}
```

In your `JobsCtrl`, inject the same `MyService` and retrieve the cached tab state like below

```
function JobsCtrl($scope, MyService) {
  var currentTab = MyService.getCurrentTab();
  alert(currentTab.label);
}
```

Here's an updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/74LmGimTlABpD3tldblJ?p=preview) with the above changes.

Comment: Both Answers are right. I accepted yours as the right answer as you kept it relevant to the scenario "tabs" and you even went a step further an edited the Plunker. *Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 2):

Create a service that will set a value and return it:

```
.service('shared', function() {

  var myValue;

  return {
    setValue: function(value) {
      myValue = value;
    },
    getValue: function() {
      return myValue;
    }
  }
});
```

Then inject it into both your controllers:

```
.controller('Ctrl1', ['shared', function(shared)......

.controller('Ctrl2', ['shared', function(shared)......
```

And then set the value from `Ctrl1`:

```
shared.setValue('somevalue');
```

And in `Ctrl2` you can just retrieve the value:

```
var mySharedValue = shared.getValue();
```